# Unable to install Nokia-RED plugin in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse-plugin, robotframework

I tried to install Nokia-RED in Eclipse indigo.

I got the following error

```
 Missing requirement: RED Robot Editor 0.7.2.201610210837 (org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin 0.7.2.201610210837) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 3.106.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: RED - Robot Editor version 0.7.2 0.7.2.201610210837 (org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.feature.feature.group 0.7.2.201610210837)
    To: org.robotframework.ide.eclipse.main.plugin [0.7.2.201610210837]
```

can any one help what exactly missed and how can come out this

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: Hi again! doesn't look like it supports INDIGO! "RED feature only: Eclipse Neon (v 4.6),Eclipse Mars (v 4.5) or Luna (v 4.4)" This is what I read from its release notes.

Comment: Thanks for your help waman, i didn't read this point

Comment: Just in case you want to use eclipse to write tests, you can also try RobotFramework Plugin.

Comment: yes, i am currently using that...i just want to try RED also

Comment: looking for any particular feature? or as you say just out of curiosity? :)

Comment: I just read some where there like RED is similar to RIDE, as i have experience on eclipse, i thought it is better to RED instead of RIDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"RED feature only: Eclipse Neon (v 4.6),Eclipse Mars (v 4.5) or Luna (v 4.4)"